# unix sed, replace field at a specific row and column in the same file

Tags: sed, awk

I have a text file with 4 columns delimited by comma.
As I am reading each record in a loop, I want to add a value to the 5th column depending on a condition.
So if I know the row number and column number, how can I use awk/sed commands to replace/set value at that particular field without using temporary files?
I want to update the file (directly) that I am reading from

```
inp.txt
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
```

Thanks,
-sri

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly edit the file with either `awk` or `sed`.  Some versions of `sed` have an option (`-i`) that works with a temporary file and overwrites the original file, but it does not actually edit the file in place.  This is not a big deal.  Just do:

```
$ awk 'NR==5{ $(NF+1) = "new value"}1' OFS=, FS=, input-file > tmp.$$
$ mv tmp.$$ input-file
```

To add a new column to row 5 of `input-file`.  If you wish, you can use `ed` to edit the file, but it makes more sense to use a temporary file.  If you want to pretend that you aren't using a temporary file, and your sed supports `-i`, you can do the same thing with:

```
sed -i '5s/$/,new value/' input-file
```

Even though most utilitites do not allow in-place modification of the file, it is simple to use one of the following `sh` functions to emulate that behavior using temporary files:

```
edit() { local f=$1; shift; "$@" < $f > $f.$$ && mv $f.$$ $f; }  # Break hard links
edit() { local f=$1; shift; "$@" < $f > $f.$$ && cat $f.$$ > $f && rm $f.$$; }
```

With either of these, you could use `awk` to give the appearance of editing files in-place using `edit filename awk awk-cmds`.  The first version breaks hard links, but uses slightly less IO.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for sed, but the purpose of awk isn't to edit files in place but to write to stdout.

But anyway, here's a solution you don't need a loop for, pretending the condition is that the entry in column 4 is an h.

```
awk -F ',' '{ if ($4 == "h") print $0",z"; else print $0","}' inp.txt > out.txt
```

output:

```
a,b,c,d,
e,f,g,h,z
i,j,k,l,
```

Comment: The above could be written more concisely as: `awk -F ',' '{print $0 FS ($4 == "h" ? "z" : "")}' inp.txt > out.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i -F, -lane 'if($.==<row number>){$F[<column_number>-1]+=<add your stuff here>}print join(",",@F)' your_file
```

tested below:

```
>cat temp
b,c,d,g
r,g,d,s
```

execute for changing the 3rd column in second row:

```
>perl -i -F, -lane 'if($.==2){$F[2]=10}print join(",",@F)' temp
> cat temp
b,c,d,g
r,g,10,s
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?
this is the version don't using any temporary files.

```
[a@b ~]$ cat tmp | sed 's_^\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)_\1,\2,\3,\4_g' 
inp.txt
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l

[a@b ~]$ cat tmp | sed 's_^\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)_\1,sth,\3,\4_g'
inp.txt
a,sth,c,d
e,sth,g,h
i,sth,k,l

[a@b ~]$ sed -ie 's_^\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)_\1,sth,\3,\4_g' tmp
[a@b ~]$ cat tmp
inp.txt
a,sth,c,d
e,sth,g,h
i,sth,k,l
```

Cheers,

Comment: It IS using a temporary file. Check your sed documentation.